# Как с PHP привести все даты к одному формату?

Tags: php

Есть база данных в которой порядка 600 записей у записей есть дата публикации которую кто только не вводил как попало. В результате в одной колонке имею такие типы дат:

12-08-14

31/08/15

15.01.13

Как бы мне все их массово привести к формату timestamp? ну или хотябы к какому-то одному?

**Мои фантазии:**

Я примерно представляю это так: делаю выбор всех записей из бд - далее нужно составить некое хитрое условие if (формат типа 12-08-14) далее foreach где все записи прошедшие через условие формата 1 преобразуются в timestamp и обновляется строка в БД. Соответственно запускаю файл на исполнение. Ну и так повторяем с каждым типом формата.

**Вопрос:**

Собственно как сделать условие для типа определённого формата даты? И как сделать преобразование оного в timestamp?

Признаюсь - мои навыки PHP весьма скромные, по этому буду очень признателен за развёрнутые примеры. Благодарю за внимание.

Comment: если гарантированно каждый элемент занимает 2 цифры, т.е. и день и месяц и год имеют по две цифры, то спокойно вырезается либо substr, либо регулярки.... хотя регуляркой можно отрезать в принципе сразу да и дело с концом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться штатным классом `DateTime`. Для приведённых форматов:

```
function normalizeDate($input) {
    $possibleFormats = [
        'd-m-y',
        'd/m/y',
        'd.m.y',
    ];
    foreach ($possibleFormats as $format) {
        $rDate = \Datetime::createFromFormat($format, $input);
        if (!$rDate) {
            continue; // точно не этот формат
        }
        if ($rDate->format($format) == $input) {
            // перепроверили формат, это именно нужный
            return $rDate->format('Y-m-d');
        }
    }
    throw new \exception('unknown format in date string '.$input);
}

$testInput = [
    '12-08-14',
    '31/08/15',
    '15.01.13',
];

foreach ($testInput as $input) {
    echo $input, "\t=> ",normalizeDate($input),PHP_EOL;
}
```

Привожу к стандартному для баз данных формату год-месяц-день типа данных `date`. Всё-таки надо использовать подходящие типы данных.

Отдельно поясню странную вторую проверку: класс datetime считает, что дата может быть указана не обязательно согласно календарю. Например, допустима дата с 20 месяцем, что класс интерпретирует как август последующего года. Поэтому я форматирую дату обратно в исходный формат и проверяю, совпадает ли она.

Comment: Благодарю, очень интересное решение! Я так понимаю в массив возможных форматов можно добавить и другие, не обязательно что бы они были в том же порядке (например 'm/d/y',) верно? И ещё момент как я должен составить запросы в бд? Цикл на извлечение/ внутри второй цикл на обновление и на входе вызов функции?

Comment: Да, распознаваемые обозначения формата описаны вот тут: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php m/d/y как вариант тоже можно указать. Только единственный момент - как определить даже человеку, 10/01/16 - это 10 января или 1 октября? Обновления в базе - для всего-то 600 строк производительность без существенной разницы, поэтому запрос на обновление сразу внутри цикла простое и рабочее решение.

Comment: Спасибо за наводки, очень доходчиво. По поводу формата в том и особенность, что в зависимости от сепаратора отличается порядок, примера где 01/02 будут в одном случае первое февраля а во втором второе января, не случится. В базе примерно так: сепаратор точка всегда - d.m.y, сепаратор тире - m-d-y, сепаратор слеш - d/m/y

Comment: Тогда нет проблем, приведённый пример функции форматы с разными разделителями не перепутает.

Answer (score 0):

Если формат всегда определяется маской `dd-mm-yy`, где `-` некий разделитель, то можно все сделать одним апдейтом в БД. Для MySQL это будет выглядеть так:

```sql
UPDATE mytable SET
  fld_timestamp =
    STR_TO_DATE(
      CONCAT(
        SUBSTRING(fld_str, 1, 2),
        '-',
       SUBSTRING(fld_str, 4, 2),
        '-',
        SUBSTRING(fld_str, 7)
      ),
      '%d-%m-%y'
    )
```

- вначале вычленяем день, месяц и год из строки
- далее формируем строку но уже известного формата и с известным разделителем
- преобразовываем эту строку в дату

Comment: Благодарю за информацию! В том-то и сложность, что форматов несколько.

Comment: @MarkBg Ну тогда Вам нужно, для начала, разработать алгоритм идентификации формата